# Why is the string index out of range when calling this lambda command?

Tags: python, indexing

I made this function as part of a tkinter calculator in order to generate all of the calculator buttons through a single function as opposed to creating them one by one.  I'm getting the following error:

```
line 49, in <lambda>
    button_list[i].configure(command = lambda: self.num_press(button_characters[i]))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The error comes up for the index called on the configure line by lambda, although the index used (`button_characters[i]`) works fine with no problems earlier in the function when setting the button text.  The num_press function at the moment does the following.

```
def num_press(self, num):
        print(num)
```

Could somebody please help me and inform me why the command isn't working and why it says the index is out of range?? I've had a look around online and haven't found anything.

Comment: The num_press function is inside of another class, I have passed the methods of that class into the class containing the shown function hence why "self" is used infront of num_press when calling it

Comment: please add additional info to the question by hitting the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51870321/edit) button

Comment: Added full code :) Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Devin, if `num_process` is in another class, it should not be accessed using `self`. Did you mean to use something like  `lambda x: x.num_process`  ?

Comment: What does the x represent in that command? Sorry I'm just starting out with tkinter and didn't know how else to access the method inside of another class

Comment: You should use lambda as this: `lambda arguments: expressions` which is equal to `f` in `def f(arguments): return expressions`

Comment: Part of the requirements of the program I'm constructing is that there needs to be 1 class to draw the GUI up and another class for the logic and functionality of the GUI (math operations etc)

Comment: @KevinFang the "expressions" is equal to f?

Comment: @Devin f is a `method`, not an expression, a simple example: assign `addone = lambda x: x+1`, then you can use it like `addone(5)` which will gives you 6

Comment: In your case, you need to pass this `method` as an argument of `configure`, and while you did not pass an argument as the answers said, so you won't get what you expected.

Comment: As explained by others, x is just the argument passed to `lambda`.

Comment: @KevinFang how would I pass the method as an argument of configure if it's in a different class? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @Devin 1) the argument `command` in method `configure` will take a method as the argument. 2) Lambda function creates a temporary method only works within this line. 3) Your GUI class inherits from `CalculatorFunctions` so you're able to use self here. The accepted answer shows the correct solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `button_list[i]` in the lambda expression is not evaluated and translated into the character when creating the lambda function, but when it is being executed. In your case that means that each time you press a button it tries to acces `button_list[16]`, since `i=16` at that point. You can see the same behaviour when you set `i` to a different value:

```
def create_number_buttons(self):
    button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
    i = 0
    button_list = []
    for row_counter in range(2,6):
        for column_counter in range(4):
            button_list.append(Button(root, pady=25, padx=35, text=button_characters[i]))
            button_list[i].grid(row=row_counter, column=column_counter, sticky="NSEW")
            button_list[i].configure(command=lambda : self.num_press(button_characters[i]))
            i += 1
    i=0
```

Now each time you press any button, the `7` will be printed on screen. Since `i` has a value of 0 when the löambda expression is executed. You can circumvent that problem by doing something like this:

```
def create_number_buttons(self):
    button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
    i = 0
    button_list = []
    for row_counter in range(2,6):
        for column_counter in range(4):
            button_list.append(Button(root, pady=25, padx=35, text=button_characters[i]))
            button_list[i].grid(row=row_counter, column=column_counter, sticky="NSEW")
            button_list[i].configure(command=lambda c=button_characters[i]: self.num_press(c))
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`range(2, 6)` gives you 4 options, and `range(4)` gives you another 4 options. 4 times 4 equals 16, which is the length of your string. But, all these lambdas reference the same `i` variable. That is your problem:

```
button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
i = 0
button_list = []
functions = []
for row_counter in range(2, 6):
    for column_counter in range(4):
        functions.append(lambda: print(button_characters[i]))
        i += 1

for f in functions:
    f()
```

To resolve the issue, do the following:

```
button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
i = 0
button_list = []
functions = []
for row_counter in range(2, 6):
    for column_counter in range(4):
        functions.append(lambda x=i: print(button_characters[x]))
        i += 1

for f in functions:
    f()
```